# Invalid date ‘Thu Aug 18 18:59:59 EST 2022’

Tags: bash

I'm getting date from csv file which is in EST format. Tried to convert date to sec and Getting error Invalid date ‘Thu Aug 18 18:59:59 EST 2022’ Please help

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x
date=`/bin/date`
TodayDateSec="$(/bin/date "+%s")"
while IFS=, read -r Name StartDate EndDate;
do
        if [ -z "$EndDate" ]; then
                echo "$EndDate details not exists"
        else
                echo "Name: $Name; StartDate: $StartDate; EndDate: $EndDate";
                #date=`/bin/date`
                EndDateSec="$(/bin/date -d "$EndDate" +'%s')";
                DiffDays="$(( ( EndDateSec - TodayDateSec )/86400 ))"
                echo "***********$DiffDays************"
        if [[ "$DiffDays" -lt 30 ]]; then
                echo "Certificate is going to expire in $DiffDays. Please take required action"

        fi
    fi
done < sample3.csv
```

Output:

```
Name: CertName; StartDate: StartDate; EndDate: EndDate
/bin/date: invalid date ‘EndDate’
***********-19195************
Certificate is going to expire in -19195. Please take required action
Name:  sslcertificates; StartDate: Thu Dec 17 19:00:00 EST 2020; EndDate: Thu Aug 18 18:59:59 EST 2022
/bin/date: invalid date ‘Thu Aug 18 18:59:59 EST 2022’
***********-19195************
Certificate is going to expire in -19195. Please take required action
```

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the problem by using `0xC2 0xA0` (aka `&nbsp;`) instead of a normal space character, so it might be a good idea to check what's in your `$EndDate` variable. Can you post the output of `printf %s "$EndDate" | xxd`?

Comment: Hi Fravadona, Below is the output:
Name: Name; StartDate: StartDate; EndDate: EndDate
/bin/date: invalid date ‘EndDate’
***********-19195************
Certificate is going to expire in -19195. Please take required action
Name: \ sslcertificates; StartDate: Thu\ Dec\ 17\ 19:00:00\ EST\ 2020; EndDate: Thu\ Aug\ 18\ 18:59:59\ EST\ 2022
/bin/date: invalid date ‘Thu Aug 18 18:59:59 EST 2022’
***********-19195************
Certificate is going to expire in -19195. Please take required action

Comment: EndDate: Thu Aug 18 18:59:59 EST 2022. I'm just trying to convert this to seconds. getting invalid date..
Name: , StartDate: , EndDate getting from .csv file
-bash-4.2$ cat sample3.csv
CertName,StartDate,EndDate
 sslcertificates,Thu Dec 17 19:00:00 EST 2020,Thu Aug 18 18:59:59 EST 2022

Comment: I deleted my first comment, see my updated one

Comment: Updated comments in above for your updated one.

Comment: I can't see the output of `xxd`, it should be something like `0000000: 5468 7520 4175 6720 3138 c2a0 3138 3a35  Thu Aug 18..18:5`
`0000010: 393a 3539 2045 5354 2032 3032 32         9:59 EST 2022`. please edit your question for adding the information, because the comments can't be formatted correctly

Comment: I'm getting xxd: command not found

Comment: You can replace `xxd` with `hexdump -C` or the standard `od -t x1`